# ExecuteBatchAsync() throws System.TimeoutException after running for some hours

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This is an interesting one: 
I have a console app running on a farm of XS Azure VMs sucking events (~1KB each) from EventHubs and storing them in Azure Table Storage. We got lots of events every day: ~10M. I am batching the events using ExecuteBatchAsync() - avg batch size is 10 events.The app runs quite well for a few hours, but after around 24hrs all nodes become sluggish and there are lots of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout."
I have the following retry policy:

```
TableRequestOptions reqOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
{
  MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
            RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300), 10),
            LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryOnly
        };
```

And this in my web.config:

```
expect100Continue="false" 
useNagleAlgorithm="false"
add address="*" maxconnection="24"
```

Any clues? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try different VM size/disk mode (Premium, which does not work with the XS one)?
It looks like you could hit the limits.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/
Also i would not say that XS can be used for production or testing/debugging due to its nature.

Comment: Thanks Alezandr, I just move the load to an array of A1, and I am testing during 24hrs.. I will let you know the results. So far it is looking good..

Comment: If that will be the solution, please mark the reply as the answer. If not, let's continue to troubleshoot :-)

Comment: Thanks Alexandr, I just completed >24hr without timeout using this new configuration, so I will consider this as closed. Many thanks!